# Help with discrete mathematics proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction

I am to prove $A_0\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_0\cap A_i), n\ge 2$ by induction.

I started out like this:

Step 1: Prove that $A_0\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_0\cap A_i)$ holds for $n = 2$

$$A_0\cap(A_1\cup A_2) = (A_0\cap A_1)\cup (A_0\cap A_2) $$

Step 2: Assume it holds true for $n = k$

$$A_0\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i) = \bigcup_{i=1}^k (A_0\cap A_i)$$

Step 3: $n = k+1$

\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1} (A_0\cap A_i) &=\bigcup_{i=1}^k (A_0\cap A_i)\cup(A_0\cap A_{k+1}) \\
&= (A_0\cap A_1)\cup (A_0\cap A_2)...\cup(A_0\cap A_k)\cup(A_0\cap A_{k+1}) \\
&= \bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}(A_0\cap A_{k+1})
\end{align*}

Am I right in this, or if not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Step 3 is wrong ... After the first line, you have to replace the "big cup" part with its equivalent expression according to step 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

$$A_0\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i) = \bigcup_{i=1}^k (A_0\cap A_i)$$

Then it follows that

$$[A_0\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i)]
\cup [A_0\cap A_{k+1}]
 = [\bigcup_{i=1}^k (A_0\cap A_i)] \cup [A_0\cap A_{k+1}]
$$

Hence (By Applying the "factoring" Property to the Left hand side)

$$A_0\cap[(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i)
\cup A_{k+1}]
 = [\bigcup_{i=1}^k (A_0\cap A_i)] \cup [A_0\cap A_{k+1}]
$$

Thus (re-indexing)

$$A_0\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1} A_i)
 = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1} (A_0\cap A_i) 
$$
As is required